# Sort a list based on another list's values

Tags: c#

I have two lists: `finalAnswers` and `draftAnswers`, where `finalAnswers[i]` is related to `draftAnswers[i]` and they both have the same size.

I want to sort `finalAnswers` in a way, that elements `i++`, having `draftAnswers[i].ID!=0` are appeared at the top and then the others.

Assume that finalAnswers is:

```
finalAnswers[1].Name = "a";
finalAnswers[2].Name = "b";
finalAnswers[3].Name = "c";
```

And corresponding elements in draftAnswers:

```
draftAnswers[1].ID = 1;
draftAnswers[2].ID = 0;
draftAnswers[3].ID = 2;
```

Once sorted, the finalAnswers is:

```
finalAnswers[1].Name = "a";
finalAnswers[2].Name = "c";
finalAnswers[3].Name = "b";
```

I tried using usual `orderBy`, but it's not straightforward in this case. Any suggestions are appretiated.

**UPDATE:**
Class:

```
class A 
{
    public int id;
    public int tID;
    public int cID;
    public string Name;
}
```

Values:

```
var finalAnswers = new List<A>() { new A() { id = 7, tID = 10, cID = 50, Name="Q1" }, 
                                   new A() { id = 8, tID = 20, cID = 30, Name="Q2" }, 
                                   new A() { id = 9, tID = 30, cID = 20, Name="Q3" } 
                                 };

var draftAnswers = new List<A>() { new A() { id = 1, tID = 10, cID = 50, Name="Q5" }, 
                                   new A() { id = 0, tID = 20, cID = 30, Name="Q2" }, 
                                   new A() { id = 1, tID = 30, cID = 20, Name="Q3" } 
                                 };
```

Sorting:

```
draftAnswers = draftAnswers.OrderBy(d=>d.id).ToList();
finalAnswers = finalAnswers.OrderBy(b => draftAnswers.FindIndex(a => a.tID == b.tID && a.cID == b.cID)).ToList();
```

OUTPUT (finalAnswer IDs):

```
8
7
9
```

EXPECTED:

```
7
9
8
```

The `orderBy` is not sorting in acsending order - [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zWKrBy#)

Comment: Rather than asking for someone to start from scratch and do it for you, you should post your best `OrderBy` attempt as a way of showing some effort

Comment: so does finalAnswers have an ID field as well? if not then you are not doing this right

Comment: @Steve yes it does have, but it doesn't correspond to the one in draftAnswers.

Comment: @Plutonix, will add shortly.

Comment: so whats the relation between final and draft answers? you might need to provide a better example. Having trouble understanding the question

Comment: If they represent the final and draft version for a single actor, why are they in parallel arrays at all?  A `List<T>` would make it simple to sort as well as keep closely related data together

Comment: @Steve draftAnswers[i] is the draft answer for finalAnswers[i]. There is no they have same tID, cID properties. That's the only way how they relate.

Comment: @Plutonix, they are parallel, because in the view I show them in parallel.

Comment: you can choose to show them in parallel but the data can still be stored inside one object.

Comment: What does each element in the arrays `finalAnswers` and `draftAnswers` look like? Are they same, or different? Also, how is `ID` used to sort items in `finalAnswers`? The expected result you've shown is not obvious.

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ they have the same set of properties, but different values. Only tID and cID properties are the same.

Comment: @JCaptain Please add this information [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49904381/edit) along with the code you have already tried.

Comment: The sorted items in your sample do not correspond with the `ID` property of the items in `draftAnswers`. `draftAnswers[1].ID == 1` (the middle ID value), and `finalAnswers[1].Name == "a"` (the corresponding item with the same index), yet you have "a" sorted to index 1 at the end. Shouldn't it be in the middle, at index `2`? Or is there some other "mapping" that you aren't showing? Also, what happened to items at index `0`?

Comment: Updated and added example. Apologies for inconsistency at the beginning.

Comment: Btw, you have _--what seems to be--_ a typo in your fiddle, where you wrote `.. b => finalAnswers.FindIndex ..` instead of `.. b => draftAnswers.FindIndex ..` which produces a totally different result. Just wanted to clear that up so no one else gets confused.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me why you expect the ordering to be `7, 9, 8`. Can you please describe how you are trying to order these items?

Comment: @RufusL, first, I sort the draft answers based on the ID, resulting 1;1;0, secondly, based on the order of the items in draft answers, I sort the final answers, so based on the matching tID and cID. that is why, then the resulting should be 7,9,8. If it's not clear, I will try to add  some details in the question

Answer (score 0):

So, you're sorting your `finalAnswers` list using the following line:<sup>1</sup>

```
finalAnswers = finalAnswers.OrderBy(b => draftAnswers.FindIndex(a => a.tID == b.tID && a.cID == b.cID)).ToList();
```

Which does what it's supposed to, except it has two problems:

- It doesn't take into account the condition: `draftAnswers[i].id!=0`.
- You are matching by the properties values, not by the index as your original requirements are.

If the second point isn't an issue for you, then you can keep that line as is, and simply change the way you sort the `draftAnswers` list using the [`ThenBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743(v=vs.110).aspx) method to take into account excluding the items with `.id == 0`:

```
draftAnswers = draftAnswers.OrderBy(d => d.id == 0).ThenBy(d => d.id).ToList();
finalAnswers = finalAnswers.OrderBy(b => draftAnswers.FindIndex(a => a.tID == b.tID &&
                                                                a.cID == b.cID)).ToList();
```

However, I see no reason for you to keep using two separate lists. You could simply merge them into a `List<KeyValuePair>` where the `Key`s are your `draftAnswers` items and the `Value`s are the `finalAnswers` items. And then you can use `ThenBy()` the same way as above, in order to sort the list based on the two conditions you have.

Something like the following would work just fine:

```
var mixed = new List<KeyValuePair<A, A>>()
{ new KeyValuePair<A, A>(new A() { id = 1, tID = 10, cID = 50, Name = "Q5" },  // draft.
                         new A() { id = 7, tID = 10, cID = 50, Name = "Q1" }), // final.
  new KeyValuePair<A, A>(new A() { id = 0, tID = 20, cID = 30, Name = "Q2" },  // draft.
                         new A() { id = 8, tID = 20, cID = 30, Name = "Q2" }), // final.
  new KeyValuePair<A, A>(new A() { id = 1, tID = 10, cID = 50, Name = "Q5" },  // etc.
                         new A() { id = 9, tID = 30, cID = 20, Name = "Q3" })};

mixed = mixed.OrderBy(a => a.Key.id == 0).ThenBy(a => a.Key.id).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("finalAnswers IDs:");
// Print the IDs of the values (finalAnswers).
foreach (var item in mixed)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value.id);

Console.WriteLine("\ndraftAnswers IDs:");
// Print the IDs of the keys (draftAnswers).
foreach (var item in mixed)
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key.id);
```

This will have your desired output for both lists. [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EGzaZT).

Hope that helps.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You have *--what seems to be--* a typo in your fiddle, where you wrote `.. b => finalAnswers.FindIndex ..` instead of `.. b => draftAnswers.FindIndex ..` which produces a totally different result. Just wanted to clear that up so no one else gets confused.</sub>

Comment: yeah, that's a typo ( Thanks for mentioninf. The thing is that I want to keep the lists separately and not to have them as key-value pair (

Comment: @JCaptain If you want to keep them separately, you can ignore the section that starts with _"However, I see no reason for you to keep using two separate lists"_ and simply use the code that's above that paragraph. Let me know if you have any issues with that part or if it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you mentioned that the `OrderBy` should produce an order of: `1,1,0`, however that would be `OrderByDescending`. `OrderBy` is *ascending*, so it orders them `0,1,1`. But regardless of which way you sort the `draftAnswers`, the result will be (using `TId`): `20,10,30`, or the opposite, `30,10,20`. Note that when using `OrderBy`, if two entries have the same value, their relative postions remain as they were. That's why you have the result you do.

So you aren't going to get your expected result by sorting on the `id` field alone. One way you *can* get that result (if that's what you want), is to use a `ThenBy` to further sort on the `cID` field:

```
draftAnswers = draftAnswers
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.id)
    .ThenByDescending(d => d.cID)
    .ToList();

finalAnswers = finalAnswers
    .OrderBy(b => draftAnswers.FindIndex(a => a.tID == b.tID && a.cID == b.cID))
    .ToList();
```